# Uncaught Error: Sys.InvalidOperationException: 'DocMapUpdatePanelId' is not a property or an existing field

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, rdlc, windows-server-2012-r2

I am building an asp.net C# application which uses buttons to retrieve and display RDLC reports within a View. The reports load without issue on localhost but when placed on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 64-bit and served through IIS version 8.5 the error:

**Uncaught Error: Sys.InvalidOperationException: 'DocMapUpdatePanelId'
 is not a property or an existing field.**

is given and none of the reports display. It looks like this:
[image]

- Application was built in Visual Studio 2015.
- .NET 3.5 Report Viewer 2012 and Report Viewer 2015 are both installed
- Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server 2012 and 2014

**Default.aspx**

```
<asp:View ID="reportView" runat="server">
                    <div class="div-view-title"><h3>TURNOUT REPORTS</h3></div>
                    <div style="padding-left: 0%;">

                        <asp:Button ID="btnCONSTITUENCY_REPORT" runat="server" Text="CONSTITUENCY REPORT" style="background-color: #ade1ff;background: linear-gradient(#ade1ff, #6facd0);position: relative; width: 250px;height: 90px;margin: 12px; box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #716f6f;background-size: 100% 100%;background-repeat: no-repeat;" OnClick="btnCONSTITUENCY_REPORT_Click" />
                        <asp:Button ID="btnLOCATION_NAME_REPORT" runat="server" Text="LOCATION REPORT" style="background-color: #ade1ff;background: linear-gradient(#ade1ff, #6facd0);position: relative; width: 200px;height: 90px;margin: 12px; box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #716f6f;background-size: 100% 100%;background-repeat: no-repeat;" OnClick="btnLOCATION_NAME_REPORT_Click" />
                        <asp:Button ID="btnEPMVTR_SECTION_REPORT" runat="server" Text="EPMVTR SECTION REPORT" style="background-color: #ade1ff;background: linear-gradient(#ade1ff, #6facd0);position: relative; width: 250px;height: 90px;margin: 12px;    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #716f6f;background-size: 100% 100%;background-repeat: no-repeat;" OnClick="btnEPMVTR_SECTION_REPORT_Click"/>
                    </div>
                    <div>



                    </div>
                </asp:View>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
protected void btnCONSTITUENCY_REPORT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsUserSessionExpired())
        lblError.Text = "Session Expired";

    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl viewCont = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)FindControl("lbtnReportsViewParent");
    if (viewCont != null)
    {
        viewCont.Style.Add("background-color", "#e4e4e4");
        viewCont.Style.Add("background", "linear-gradient(#a4a8ce, #e7e6ff)");
    }

    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl viewCont2 = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)FindControl("lbtnElevenViewParent");
    if (viewCont2 != null)
    {
        viewCont2.Style.Remove("background-color");
        viewCont2.Style.Remove("background");
    }

    try
    {
        ReportViewerCONSTITUENCY_REPORT.Reset();
        ReportDataSource rptdsrc = new ReportDataSource("PVC_SSVGE_CONSTITUENCY_REPORT_DataSet", GetData(@"with tosum as
            (
            select e.cnstncy_nbr, cnstncy_nm, e.epmv_pk, e.elctn_id, e.epm_type, 
            e.voting_location,e.location_address, e.stations, e.total_elctr as 'total_elctr',
             e.voter_turnout_11am as 'total_turnout_11am',  e.voter_turnout_3pm as 'total_turnout_3pm', e.misc as 'total_turnout_misc', e.aud_uid
            from EPMVTR_STATS e inner join UNI_CNSTNCY c 
            on e.cnstncy_nbr = c.cnstncy_nbr and e.elctn_id = c.elctn_id 
            where e.cnstncy_nbr = c.cnstncy_nbr
            ) select cnstncy_nbr, cnstncy_nm, epm_type, sum(total_elctr) [total_elctr], sum(total_turnout_11am) [total_turnout_11am] ,sum(total_turnout_3pm) [total_turnout_3pm]
            ,sum(total_turnout_misc) [total_turnout_misc]
              from tosum
              group by cnstncy_nbr, cnstncy_nm, epm_type
            order by cnstncy_nbr; ").Tables["resultsTable"]);//GetData("Select * from EPMVTR_STATS").Tables["resultsTable"]);
        //ReportDataSource rptdsrcSum = new ReportDataSource("PVC_SSVGE_CONSTITUENCY_REPORT_DataSet", GetData("select e.cnstncy_nbr, cnstncy_nm, e.epmv_pk, e.elctn_id, e.epm_type, e.voting_location,e.location_address, e.stations, e.total_elctr, e.voter_turnout_11am, e.voter_turnout_3pm, e.misc, e.aud_uid, e.aud_uid from EPMVTR_STATS e inner join UNI_CNSTNCY c on e.cnstncy_nbr = c.cnstncy_nbr and e.elctn_id = c.elctn_id order by cnstncy_nbr").Tables["resultsTable"]);
        ReportViewerCONSTITUENCY_REPORT.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rptdsrc);
        ReportViewerCONSTITUENCY_REPORT.LocalReport.ReportPath = MapPath("~\\App_Browsers\\PVC_SSVGE_CONSTITUENCY_REPORT.rdlc");
        ReportViewerCONSTITUENCY_REPORT.LocalReport.Refresh();


    }
    catch
    {

    }


    epmMultiView.SetActiveView(viewCONSTITUENCY_REPORT);
}

protected void btnLOCATION_NAME_REPORT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsUserSessionExpired())
        lblError.Text = "Session Expired";

    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl viewCont = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)FindControl("lbtnReportsViewParent");
    if (viewCont != null)
    {
        viewCont.Style.Add("background-color", "#e4e4e4");
        viewCont.Style.Add("background", "linear-gradient(#a4a8ce, #e7e6ff)");
    }

    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl viewCont2 = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)FindControl("lbtnElevenViewParent");
    if (viewCont2 != null)
    {
        viewCont2.Style.Remove("background-color");
        viewCont2.Style.Remove("background");
    }

    try
    {
        ReportViewerLOCATION_NAME_REPORT.Reset();
        ReportDataSource rptdsrc = new ReportDataSource("PVC_SSVGE_LOCATION_NAME_REPORT_DataSet", GetData("select cnstncy_nm,e.* from EPMVTR_STATS e inner join UNI_CNSTNCY c on e.cnstncy_nbr = c.cnstncy_nbr and e.elctn_id = c.elctn_id order by cnstncy_nbr, stations").Tables["resultsTable"]);
        lbtnReportsView.Text = "Test Got here";
        ReportViewerLOCATION_NAME_REPORT.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rptdsrc);
        ReportViewerLOCATION_NAME_REPORT.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("PVC_SSVGE_LOCATION_NAME_REPORT.rdlc");
        ReportViewerLOCATION_NAME_REPORT.LocalReport.Refresh();

    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        lbtnReportsView.Text = "Exception";
    }

    epmMultiView.SetActiveView(viewLOCATION_NAME_REPORT);
}

protected void btnEPMVTR_SECTION_REPORT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsUserSessionExpired())
        lblError.Text = "Session Expired";

    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl viewCont = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)FindControl("lbtnReportsViewParent");
    if (viewCont != null)
    {
        viewCont.Style.Add("background-color", "#e4e4e4");
        viewCont.Style.Add("background", "linear-gradient(#a4a8ce, #e7e6ff)");
    }

    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl viewCont2 = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)FindControl("lbtnElevenViewParent");
    if (viewCont2 != null)
    {
        viewCont2.Style.Remove("background-color");
        viewCont2.Style.Remove("background");
    }

    try
    {
        ReportViewerEPMVTR_SECTION_REPORT.Reset();
        ReportDataSource rptdsrc = new ReportDataSource("PVC_SSVGE_EPMVTR_SECTION_REPORT_DataSet", GetData("select cnstncy_nm,e.* from EPMVTR_STATS e inner join UNI_CNSTNCY c on e.cnstncy_nbr = c.cnstncy_nbr and e.elctn_id = c.elctn_id order by cnstncy_nbr").Tables["resultsTable"]);

        ReportViewerEPMVTR_SECTION_REPORT.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rptdsrc);
        ReportViewerEPMVTR_SECTION_REPORT.LocalReport.ReportPath = MapPath("~\\App_Browsers\\PVC_SSVGE_EPMVTR_SECTION_REPORT.rdlc");
        ReportViewerEPMVTR_SECTION_REPORT.LocalReport.Refresh();
    }
    catch
    {

    }
    epmMultiView.SetActiveView(viewEPMVTR_SECTION_REPORT);
}
```

Any ideas on whats causing this error and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

there could be multiple versions of report viewer defined in your web.config file

Comment: the web.config file only references version 12. and making reference to another version would have resulted in a failed compilation.